# Print function not to print the whole page using jquery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

Currently I have a web application that contains a lot of div , menu and many others layout staff. However, What I would like to have when the user click print is only two image or one image in some case. Assume I have already get the two image url, how to remove the css of entire page and perform the print as i expected ?  Here is some code I tried , it seems it will change the whole page from the web app layout to only 2 image? Can I prevent that? thanks:

**print.css**

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    .img{
        padding:5%;
        height:100%;
        width:40%;
    }
    #img1{
        left:0px;
    }
</style>
```

**js**

```
$("#printBtn").click(function() {
    $("link[media='screen']").attr("href", "print.css");
    window.print();
});
```

**Updated:**

To be more precise, what i will do is to get the image number(s) of the current page , and only this two image will be printed. How to perform such function?

Assuming I get the id of the two img already. First of all, I need to add the class = 'img' dynamically in this two item ? What is the next step untill the print finish ?  thanks

```
<img id="img_34" src="demo/medium/Web081112_P034_medium.jpg" alt="flip book">
<img id="img_35" src="demo/medium/Web081112_P034_medium.jpg" alt="flip book">
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, but you could simply use `display:none` for elements you do not want to show in the `media="print"` css

Comment: The problem is: when the css change from media to print, the screen will change as well? If the user click cancel print, can it return to the webapp layout ? thanks

Comment: It would be ideal if the screen won't change, is it possible?

Comment: The `media="print"` will **not** do anything on the normal screen, this css will be used only when you issue a print command. Try using print preview in the browser, to see how it works.

Comment: @PranavKapoor user782104 is actually **switching** from screen CSS to print CSS. What he needs to do is use both at the same time: have a screen CSS file AND a print CSS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you change you `<link media='screen' />` to a print.css stylesheet?

It's better practice if you would just use a `screen` and a `print` stylesheet side by side. No Javascript / jQuery needed for that:

```
<!-- Default styling -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/default.css" media="screen" />

<!-- This styling is only used for printing -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/print.css" media="print" />
```

To answer your question, you can just add a div to the bottom of your page like `<div id='print-wrap'></div>` and put all your printy stuff in there.

Then, in your CSS you do something similar to this:

**default.css**

```
#print-wrap { display: none; }
```

**print.css**

```
img { display: none; }
#print-wrap { display: block; }
#img_34 { display: block !important; }
#img_35 { display: block !important; }
```

### Update

Updated the answer corresponding to the updated question. If you want just two images visible on your printed page, just hide all other images with `display: none;` and show the images you want to print using `display: block !important;`

Comment: How about when the user cancel the print/ finish the print , how to check this event? thanks

Comment: There is no native event being triggered when the print is canceled, therefore you cannot 'check' that event.

Comment: thanks , I have updated the question , may you have a look at that?

Answer (score 1):

You could make the whole page (i.e) body hidden.

With CSS:

```
body {
visiblilty:hidden;
}
```

Then make your div visible (where your image is rendered)

```
#yourdiv{
visibility:visible;
}
```

Then use window.print(); which would print `#yourdiv`

Comment: yes, this is much better then set the interface element to displayt:none one by one?

Comment: Wouldn't recommend that. You hide the whole body and try to make a child visibile while the body is still hidden.

Comment: Yes, you could use `visibility:hidden`; The `display:none;` would actually remove the space layout.

Answer (score 1):

Your `print css` and `screen css` will not be used together while you are on screen (webpage), the print css will be referred **ONLY** when your media is print (print).

Whenever a print command is issued, the print css is referred along with the `screen css`, with print specific css properties having a higher priority.
Whenever, you are done and return to the same page, the page WILL return as is before the print command was issued.

From [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-types),

> **print**
>
> Intended for paged material and for documents viewed on screen
>   in print preview mode.

In your specific case, you want to print only 2 images, rather than all of them. So,

`print.css :`

```
img {
    display: none;
}
#img_34, #img_35 {      /*Image id's*/
    display: block;
}
```

To test pages using a print css, simply do a print preview in the browser to get an idea of how it looks, and press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to return to the page.

If you are interested in reading up more about print css, and guidelines, **[this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/)** is a good article by [SmashingMagazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com)